# leak in @property setter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a custom UIView that I add as a subview in several places throughout my app. I send the view a NSMutable Array by setting a property and it displays a graph of notes. This works fine except for one view in my app. I use this code in the viewDidLoad section of each view that contains the graph.

```
endNoteDisplay =[[NoteDisplay alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,180)];
endNoteDisplay.tag = 100;
endNoteDisplay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Note_Bkg.png"]];
NSMutableArray *tmpNts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"C", @"E", @"G", @"A",nil];
endNoteDisplay.noteSpread = tmpNts;
[tmpNts release];
[self.view addSubview:endNoteDisplay];
[endNoteDisplay release];
```

- If I remove the `endNoteDisplay.noteSpread = tmpNts;` line everything works just fine no leak.
- If I leave it in Instruments is showing a memory leak. The leak occurs when I leave the current view (where I display the notes) and return to the previous view (it has a table with a list of different note options to be displayed).
- My app is working as expected and this is the only leak that is coming up.

Can anybody tell me why this is generating a leak? the `noteSpread` property in my `NoteDisplay` is set to `nonatomic retain`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instruments says I have a memory leak, but I don't see it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214327/instruments-says-i-have-a-memory-leak-but-i-dont-see-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NoteDisplay's dealloc you need to send release to the instance variable that backs noteSpread.

Comment: +1 I agree with this answer.  Your code above looks fine.  If the noteSpread property / variable of the NoteDisplay class is leaking, make sure you are releasing `noteSpread` in the dealloc of `NoteDisplay`.

Comment: This worked out perfectly! I had not released the ivar that was backing noteSpread in the NoteDisplay class. Not sure why the leak didn't show when I used it in other places but, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 3):

Does the `-dealloc` method in NoteDisplay release the noteSpread property?

Answer (score -2):

you can use this combine statement:

```
endNoteDisplay.noteSpread = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"C", @"E", @"G", @"A",nil];
```

which will eliminate these 2 lines,

```
NSMutableArray *tmpNts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"C", @"E", @"G", @"A",nil];
endNoteDisplay.noteSpread = tmpNts;
```

and will also remove the leak:

just be sure to release the "noteSpread" in the controller when you're done with your work.